# How to recognize a column in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have merged two data sets (data1.csv and data2.csv) and created a data file to run the analyses on. But, when I do the analysis, R cannot recognize some of my columns (variables). My analysis is a multinational logit one.
The code for analysis is:

```
 library(nnet)
 mlogit<- multinom(groupadmit~mid_pop, tot_male10, tot_female10, male16, 
 tot_female16, agemean10, agemean16, IMD_score, IMD_score2, data = 
 admitqof10_16)
```

and the error is:

```
 Error in model.frame.default(formula = groupadmit ~ mid_pop, data = 
 admitqof10_16,  : 
 object 'male16' not found
```

I tried a couple of ways to solve the problem. For example, I use `ls()` to see whether the created data.table is in the R or not and it was there. I changed the name of the variable, but again it does not work. I exported the created data and imported it again. But, I have failed.

May someone please help me know why this problem happens and what I can do to resolve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In R's formula syntax you need to *add* predictor variables, i.e. `groupadmit ~ mid_pop + tot_male10 + tot_female10 + ...` Or `groupadmit ~ .` to include *all* variables (other than `groupadmit`) from `data`  as predictors.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, it worked , thanks.

Comment: As I recall nnet uses the same formula conventions as lm().  If that is so, nnet(groupadmit ~. ,   data = admitqof10_16 ) will work.  This is an addendum to the previous comment.